# regex remove dot from end of each word in text

Tags: java, regex

I try to remove dot only from end of each word in given text. (in java)
for example:

```
input: java html. .net node.js php.
output: java html .net node.js php
```

thanks

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: `.` is a special character in regex.  Escape it like so `\.` So for words ending with . `/\w\./gi`

Comment: You can try something like `\\.(?=[^.]*$)`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of word you could replace:

```
(\w)\.(?!\S)
```

with `$1`. Which would remove all `.` at the end of a word followed by a space or end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
String repl = "java html. .net node.js php.".replaceAll("\\.(?!\\w)", "");

// java html .net node.js php
```

Comment: I tested on the OPs use case and it works perfectly.  Works for my needs as well.  Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String str : input.split(" "))
{ 
     if(str.charAt(str.len - 1) == '.')
         str = str.substr(0, str.len - 2);

     //do something with str
}
```

I would avoid regular expressions if at all possible as they are much slower.

Comment: You do know that two `.` are removed from the example?

Comment: *«I try to remove dot only from end of **each word** in given text.»* Maybe your answer should mention a prior splitting of the input in words.

Comment: @Qtax Ah, I assumed it was one word input for some reason. I will add a loop to go through all strings entered.

Comment: @afsantos Ah, thank you. I did not notice that in my first read through. edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a regular expression, I'd recommend [using a word boundary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

```
 \.\B
```

This matches a literal dot at the end of a word boundary only.

Answer (score 0):

An elaborated solution based on Qtax's answer:

```
String s = "java html. .net node.js php.";
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("(\\w)\\.(?!\\S)", "$1");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
java html .net node.js php
```